# ajax progress bar image hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when i click a button i want to display a image and after finish the image hide. wht wrong with my script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(element).click(function(){
    $(".navigation-jpg").show();
    $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            $(".navigation-jpg").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="ajax-content">

    <img src="navigation.jpg" alt="Loading" class="loading-gif" style="display:none"/>
    <div class="ajax-response">
    </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

       </div>
```

Comment: css class name was "loading-gif" but in the code you used ".navigation-jpg"

Answer (score 2):

You are using the class `navigation-jpg` in your javascript, but are using class `loading-gif` in your HTML.  Make that consistent and you are good.

**Update:**  Other answerer also caught the use of `$(element)` instead of `$('#Button1)` on the event handler -- wanted to make sure my incomplete answer was updated.

**Update #2:**  Yet found another issue.  The javascript event handler is being attached before the HTML is found in the DOM.  The result of this is that the event handler will not be attached.  Either move the javascript below the HTML elements OR wrap the javascript code in a jQuery document.ready code like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your js code here
});
```

**Update #3:**  The ajax call itself does not have enough attributes to actually make an ajax call.  Here is a sample you may want to follow.  You need to add the type and url at a minimum.  If you are passing parameters, you will need data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

**Update #4:**  Here is a more complete code snippet that hopefully guides you to a fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// execute the javascript action after the entire DOM has been loaded
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // hide the image initially
    $(".loading-gif").hide();

    // attach the handler to the button
    $('#Button1').click(function () {
        $(".loading-gif").show();

        // provide enough information to the ajax function to make a call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some-other-page.html",
            success: function () {
                $(".loading-gif").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div class="ajax-content">
    <img src="http://localhost:2169/Image/Icon/loading.gif" alt="Loading" class="loading-gif" />
    <div class="ajax-response">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it does't work for me, event i at serverside using thread sleep

Comment: @Mickey sorry I could not fully solve your problems.  Perhaps there is something else happening with the asp:Button with runat="server" that is interfering with the javascript events.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `.navigation-jpg` class as your selector, when it's actually `.loading-gif`. And I'm guessing you don't actually leave `$(element).click...` there, you will replace it with a correct element selector yes?

```
$('#Button1').click(function(){
    $(".loading-gif").show();
    $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            $(".loading-gif").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Good catch on #Button1 -- did not catch that at first